# Setting the size of a TChart when saved/copied to clipboard

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, teechart

We have a number of charts in our application which we allow the user to generate a report in Word from. We do this by calling **CopyToClipboardBitmap** on the **TChart** and then pasting it into the Word document at the appropriate location.

However, we're having issues that the resolution of the bitmaps are based on their currently rendered size on screen. So people on low resolution desktops, or who happen to not be running the app maximized end up with quite low resolution images in the generated Word document.

We'd like to be able to set the resolution before doing the **CopyToClipboardBitmap**. Is there anyway to do this?

Note, we've tried using **CopyToClipboardMetafile** (with both true and false as the argument) and that seems to have similar issues in that the size of the image is based on the rendered size on screen. This results in the text for the axis, labels, etc. being overly large when made larger within the document. So we're back to wanting to be able to specify the render size that the **CopyToClipboardBitmap** / **CopyToClipboardMetafile** / **SaveToBitmapFile** / **SaveToMetafile** / **SaveToMetafileEnh** is based upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a TRect as parameter for the CopyToClipboardBitmap method. Ie:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tmpRect: TRect;
    tmpWidth, tmpHeight: Integer;
begin
  tmpRect:=Chart1.GetRectangle;
  tmpWidth:=tmpRect.Right-tmpRect.Left;
  tmpHeight:=tmpRect.Bottom-tmpRect.Top;
  tmpRect.Right:=tmpRect.Right+tmpWidth;
  tmpRect.Bottom:=tmpRect.Bottom+tmpHeight;
  Chart1.CopyToClipboardBitmap(tmpRect);
end;
```

I've just answered the same question in the Steema Software support forums [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15936&p=70743).

Comment: Thanks. Is this documented anywhere? We don't have access to the Steema source, and all I could find was http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TCustomTeePanel.CopyToClipboardBitmap.html, plus Delphi 2010 doesn't seem to offer autocomplete on the Steema methods (perhaps as we don't have source).

Comment: Check the library paths and build the project. Methods and Properties auto-completion should work without the sources. We'll revise the online documentation.